# Apply two onclik events on one link

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to apply two events on one link:

- 1st event to modify value of a hidden button,
- 2nd event to modify link background color (link displaying as block)

How can I do this?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
<script>
var divItems = document.getElementsByClassName("hour");

function selected(item) {
    this.clear();
    item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}

function clear() {
    for(var i=0; i < divItems.length; i++) {
        var item = divItems[i];
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function updateValue(val, event) {
    document.getElementById("hour").value = val;
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

```
<a style="display: block" class="hour" id="hour" href="#" title="11:00 AM" onclick="updateValue(this.title, event);" onclick=selected(this)>
<span>11:00 AM</span>
</a>
<input type="text" id="hour" name="hour" value="" />
```

Comment: `onclick="updateValue(this.title, event);selected(this)"`

Comment: You can not specify the same attribute more than once on an element. Instead, you should just call the two functions in one here, `onclick="updateValue(this.title, event); selected(this);"` And ideally, move away from this kind of “old-school” event handling applied via HTML attributes altogether.

Comment: BIIIG thanks Suresh and CBroe , it worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Heyo!

I personally suggest you to avoid using JS in HTML using the onclick attribute and instead the Javascript onClick event. However, if you want to use the onclick attribute, you can have two functions using `;` to split them. For example:

```
<a style="display: block" class="hour" id="hour" href="#" title="11:00 AM" onclick="updateValue(this.title, event); selected(this)">
```

Comment: Thank you emergenitro , what better method do you suggest to me? (I'm beginner++ in js) , any link ?

Comment: Heyo! w3schools is a great way to start learning Javascript, the following link contains another approach to your question. Click [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). Furthermore, going through StackOverflow's JS questions will help you out!